# how to refer the value of an xml tag that is passed as value to another xml using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that goes like this:

```
<Root>
    <Content>
        <Paragraph>
            <Image reference="folder-1/folder-2/imagefile.xml"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </Content>
</Root>
```

In the reference "folder-1/folder-2/imagefile.xml", i have the path of the image file as a value to an xml tag.

How do I access the image file and pass the path as value to the  tag's src attribute?

I tried the solution posted in [Read properties file or a text file in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810936/read-properties-file-or-a-text-file-in-xsl), but it did not work. Is there any other way that this can be done?
Any help is welcome. Thanks to all in advance.

EDITED:

The imagefile.xml contains the following code:

```
<Container>
    <Element>
        <ImagePath>
            folder/folder/imagename.jpg
        </ImagePath>
        <AltImage>
            folder/folder/altimage.jpg
        </AltImage>
    </Element>
</Container>
```

When I meant the solution did not work I meant that the img tag coming in the html output has the src attribute's value empty like this: `<img src="" alt=""></img>`

The XSL Template I use is like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Image">
    <img src="{./Container/Element/ImagePath}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

the image tag I expect to come like this

```
<img src = "folder/folder/imagename.jpg"/>
```

But it comes up as empty. In Firefox, I see a thumbnail with a broken image, kind of like the one you get when there is no image.

Comment: If it did not work, you must have some code to show. Also post what `imagefile.xml` contains.

Comment: As I said, please show the XSLT you are trying to use and the HTML you expect to get. (Also the `alt` attribute is supposed to contain a text description, not another URL.)

Comment: Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Had you done so initially or after @Tomalak's prompting, we would have answered your question for you by now.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, please go back and [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) some of the fine answers you've received to the previous questions you've asked.  Thanks.

Comment: Your xsl template has match = "Image", but where there is no Image tag in your Xml.

Comment: It seems you have not really read the answer in the thread you link to. That answer uses the `document()` function. Your code does not.

Comment: I tried the following snippet also instead of the <img> tag
`<xsl:variable name = "source">
 <xsl:value-of select="document(@reference)//Container/Element/ImagePath"/>
</xsl:variable>
<img class="image_{@align} {@style}">
 <xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:value-of select = "$source"/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</img>`
It did not work.

There is an Image tag in the first XML @fly_us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <good>
      <xsl:variable name="secondData" select="document(Root/Content/Paragraph/Image/@reference)"/>
      <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="$secondData//AltImage"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
    </good>
  </xsl:template>
```

Only thing that is important is "imagefile.xml" file should be within the same directory, where your source or first xml is!!
I have used .NET's own XslCompiledTransform and the parser looks within the folder from where the source xml comes.

Comment: Thanks for that, but how do i achieve this if they are not in the same directory? Coz i really cannot have them in the same directory.

Comment: @user They don't have to be in the *same* directory. They have to be *reachable* from that the directory where the XSLT file is. Use the appropriate relative path or absolute path, simple as that.