# Accessing xpath queries from property files

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How do I load xpath queries from a property file ?

when I tried doing this, it simply printed the text equivalent of the xpath query, rather than evaluating it.

props.xml file:

```
<strings>
<string id='msg012'>/soapNs:Envelope/soapNs:Body/schNs:processArchiveRequest/schNs:fulfillmentRequest/schNs:requestHeader/schNs:requestID</string>
```

xsl file:

```
     <sample><xsl:value-of    select="document('props.xml')//string[@id='msg012']"/></sample>
```

This post ( [Read properties file or a text file in xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810936/read-properties-file-or-a-text-file-in-xsl/10813674#10813674)) talks about substituting a text value from a property file. but, I am looking for something that loads and evaluates an xpath query from a prop file.

Comment: Dynamic XPath evaluation is part of XSLT 3.0, if you are using an earlier version you will have to check whether your processor supports it with an extension.

Comment: I am using xslt 2.0 and saxon. Is there a way to achieve this?